# How can I save a "Custom Setup" configuration for my devices in Microsoft Teams?

Tags: microphone, microsoft-teams

Every time I join a meeting in Microsoft Teams, I use the "Custom Setup" option for my microphone and camera settings. However, I have to change the microphone setting every time - Teams doesn't remember which microphone I used last time, and keeps changing the setting to the wrong device.

How can I save my camera and microphone choices, so that Teams will stop switching my microphone every time I join a meeting?

Comment: Possibly related: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/microsoft-teams-general-settings-not-saving-after/356be5fa-57e6-4858-a582-f40ffd24cdbe

Comment: The settings are for the meeting itself, if this is a corporate environment your network administrator can set default meeting device settings